# parameters of a function. local or is variable of calling function

Tags: c

this is a function

```
int func1(int c,int *d)
{

int *a=&c;
return a;
    
}
```

from above function. Is it ok to return the parameters; or not. and what about this

what if I have

```
int func2(int c,int *d)
{
...
return d;
}
```

the above looks ok.

what if

```
int func3(int x)
{
...
int y=x;
return x;
}
```

the above is also looks fine since I am returning copy of variable

are my assumptions are correct?

Comment: The first one is wrong. `c` only exists within the function so returning a pointer to it is invalid. And the type of the return value (`int *`) is incompatible with the return type defined by the function (`int`).

Comment: How can you return a int* from a function that returns int?

Comment: In the first function you return a trash pointer to local memory, in the second example you return a copy of the pointer, in the third one you return a copy of the number. In the first 2 examples you also need the return type to be `int*`.

Comment: When evaluating the correctness of a variable usage you have to consider always its scope and its lifetime. The answer is simple: the use of variable, or a pointer to it, is ok when it is in its scope and it lifetime (i.e. see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/explain-lifetime-of-a-variable-in-c-language, or google around)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int func1(int c,int *d)
{
  int *a=&c;
  return a;    
}
```

This is completely wrong. The function is declared as returning an `int` but you return a *pointer* to an `int`. Furthermore returning a pointer to a parameter is pointless because as soon as the function is terminated, the parameter no longer exists.

---

```
int func2(int c,int *d)
{
  ...
  return d;
}
```

Here again you return a pointer to `int` but the function is declared as returning an `int`.

---

```
int func3(int x)
{
  ...
  int y=x;
  return x;
}
```

This is correct but returning one of the parameters is rather pointless.